# getchar() function is not working

Tags: c, xcode

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    long nc;

    nc=0;
    while (getchar()!=EOF) {
        ++nc;
        printf("%ld\n", nc);
    }
}
```

This is the code, and when I typed a character, it will print 1 then print 2, even if I have only typed once.

I am using Xcode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This is the code, and when I typed a character, it will print 1 then
>   print 2, even if I have only typed once.

But you did press `return`, didn't you ? Try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or watch out for the newline in the loop. Maybe something like this ?

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (ch == '\n')
        continue;
    ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have, what should I do then?

Comment: @Newyo Well, `getchar` returns the newline and only after that returns `EOF`.

Comment: Thank you. I was very confused.

Comment: But if I pressed ctrl + d, why doesn't it leave the loop as I have entered an EOF?

Comment: I am sorry that I did make myself clear. What I mean is that when I typed a character such as "a", then I pressed ctrl+d, it will print 1, but I can enter another character, which shows that the program is still in the loop. it only finish the program when I press ctrl+d again.

Comment: @Newyo Press `C-D` and then return.

Comment: Depending on you particular combination of shell, pseudo-tty, and terminal emulator, EOF aka ^D may only be recognized at the beginning of a line - e.g. '<a><\n><^D>', but not '<a><^D>'.